# Do I have to install Ruby from source to get Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0 installed on my windows machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rvm, pik

I currently have Ruby 2.2.6 and Rails 5.0.1 installed on my Windows 10 machine. I have cloned an existing project that has the following settings included in its Gemfile:

```
# Lock-in Lang and Framework:
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
```

I'm having a surprisingly hard time figuring out how to get Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0 installed. Ruby has [good documentation of different installation options](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/), but I think I've exhausted the Windows options without any success. Here are a couple I tried:

- Installers: I couldn't find an option for downloading either from [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en), [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), and [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/installer#windows).
- RVM: I tried (unsuccessfully) following [this blog post](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) to install cygwin so that I could use RVM, but then saw in the comments that the author now recommends spinning up a linux VM rather that using this method.
- [Pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) and [Uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru): It appears Pik is no longer maintained, and I couldn't figure how to download new versions and ruby and rails with Uru as opposed to managing already downloaded versions.

EDIT: I also tried simply changing the version numbers for ruby and rails in the Gemfile to 2.2.6 and 5.0.1. When I do this I (very understandably) get a message when I try to use a rails command saying I need to run `bundle update rails`. When I run that rails update I get the following error: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack"`.  I've done some googling on that option, and it looks like resolving that issue might be possible but requires some more involved tinkering with my Gemfile configuration.

I think my next option is to install Ruby from the source, but I wanted to throw a question up here first to make sure I'm not missing an easier method. **So my question is - is it really this hard to get an older minor release of ruby and rails installed on Windows?** I realize that the majority of users are probably looking for the most recent release, but it doesn't seem to me that my use case is terribly unique.

Comment: I bet you could just edit the Gemfile to say`2.2.6` instead - the versions aren't that different.

Comment: I tried that and ran into a couple of different issues - would it be worth adding those to the question?  Would I be able to do the same with changing the rails version from 4.2.0 to 5.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldest available `Ruby 2.2.x` via RubyInstaller is `2.2.1`
So, the answer to your question is, "Yes, you'll have to build from source."

But then again,
`v2.x` of `gem "rack"` requires at least `Ruby v2.2.2`

And depending on what other gems are included in your `Gemfile`, you'll still have to reconfigure your `Gemfile` to get this app running.

So the best solution is probably to use the latest patch version of `Ruby 2.2.x` and lock `rails` to `4.2.x`. (The app *may not* be compatible with `Rails 5.x`)

```
# Lock-in Lang and Framework:

ruby '2.2.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'
```

Then run `bundle install` to install all the gems required by the `Gemfile`